# Two seperate online characters in Grand Theft Auto 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Playing Xbox 360, I noticed that there are multiple character slots for online play. Is money, rank, vehicles, etc. the same across both, or does progress save to the individual characters?

Answer (score 1):

Money in your bank account is shared, but nothing else is shared. i.e. cars, houses, rank, guns, etc. are not shared.